# Why does XPath's node test node() not return attribute Nodes?

Tags: xml, xpath

I've been looking at XPath's node tests ([documentation here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xpath-31-20170321/#prod-xpath31-KindTest)) and been testing them out on some examplary xml.

```
<apartment residents="4" shared="true"> 
      fries
      <!-- potatosalad -->
</apartment>
```

And while the Kindtest for attributes *//apartment/@** will return both *residents* and *shared* meaning they are both children of the apartment node, the Kindtest for any kind *//apartment/nodes()* will return the text node *fries* and the comment node *potatosalad* **but not the attribute nodes *residents* or *shared***.

This seems counter-intuitive to me and I wonder: is there a good reason for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XPath `//apartment/node()` will select all of the `apartment` element's **child** nodes, which are `*`, `processing-instruction()`, `comment()`, and `text()`.

Attributes and namespaces are special in that their parent is the element that they are "attached to", but they are not considered **child** nodes, and will not be selected from the **child** axis.

Information about the child axis from the specs (I added bolding for emphasis):

https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-xpath-31-20170321/#axes

> The child axis contains the children of the context node, which are the nodes returned by the [Section 5.3 children Accessor](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel-31/#dm-children).
>
> > **Note:** Only document nodes and element nodes have children. If the context node is any other kind of node, or if the context node is an empty document or element node, then the child axis is an empty sequence. **The children of a document node or element node may be element, processing instruction, comment, or text nodes. Attribute, namespace, and document nodes can never appear as children.**

https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-datamodel-31/#ElementNodeOverview

> 4. Exclusive of Attribute and Namespace Nodes, if a node N has a parent element E, then N must be among the children of E. (**Attribute and Namespace Nodes have a parent, but they do not appear among the children of their parent.**)

Comment: I see, I got confused because there is a nodetest called attribute making me think _//@*_ meant _//child::attribute(*)_ but in actuality its _//attribute::*_.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

"Why?" questions are always difficult. We can point to the rule in the spec that says this is what it does, but we can very rarely discover what was going on in the minds of the committee when they made the decision, if indeed there was ever a conscious decision. All we can really do is to speculate why someone might have thought this was a good design.

The decision makes sense when you realise that `node()` is a `NodeTest`, used here as an `AxisStep`. An `AxisStep` takes the form `[Axis::]NodeTest`, with the `Axis` part defaulting to "child::". It wouldn't be very useful to have a "child-or-attribute" axis, because `child-or-attribute::XYZ` would be ambiguous. So there isn't one, which means that it doesn't make sense to use it as the default axis when the `NodeTest` happens to be `node()`.

Basically there is a full syntax for axis steps, which is highly orthogonal (you can use any axis with any NodeTest) and orthogonality is highly prized by language designers. Then there is an abbreviated syntax to make common cases less verbose; the abbreviations are less orthogonal, but there is some consistency, and one of the consistent rules is that the default axis is child, except (in 2.0) where the NodeTest only selects attribute or namespace nodes.